# Passing assertions in the ClientCredentialsGrantConfig

Tags: ballerina

I have a requirement to pass a client assertion in the client credentials grant type token request as specified in the spec - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521.html.
According to the above spec, instead of client_id and client_secret, we need to specify client_assertion_type and client_assertion in the token request payload.

Below is something I tried.

Generated JWT:

```
map<json> sub = {
    "sub" : "abcd"
};

jwt:IssuerConfig issuerConfig = {
    customClaims: sub,
    issuer: "abcd",
    audience: "https://abcd/oauth2/token",
    expTime: 3000,
    signatureConfig: {
        config: {
            keyFile: "./privatekey.pem"
        }
    }
};

string jwt = check jwt:issue(issuerConfig);
```

Constructed optional params map passing the JWT:

```
map<string> jwtAssertion = {
    "client_assertion_type" : "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
    "client_assertion" : jwt
};

Passed the optional params to the client credentials config record:
oauth2:ClientCredentialsGrantConfig epicConfig = {
    tokenUrl: "https://abcd/oauth2/token",
    clientId: "abcd",
    optionalParams: jwtAssertion,
    clientSecret: "random"
};
```

But the problem here is that since client_id and client_secret are mandatory, the backend I'm trying to connect is returning a 400.

Is there any suggestion to handle this scenario where I need to send the assertion without the id and secret? Also, is there any future plan to add the support mentioned in the spec https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7521.html, to the oauth2 module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is not supported in the `oauth2` module.
We can use a separate HTTP client and get the token by sending a post request to STS. Then, manually set the obtained assertion/token in the header of the resource request.